# ImageIO.read/write slow in Websphere 8.5.5

Tags: tomcat7, javax.imageio, websphere-8, imgscalr

As a part of my web application, I am using [javax.imageio.ImageIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) for reading/writing [BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html).
Initially my app was running on **Tomcat 7**, and it was running quite fast. Since I've deployed my app to **WebSphere 8.5.5** the performance of reading/writing has significantly decreased (few times slower).

At first, I thought was that ImageIO performed bad on WebSphere due to IBM's JVM, so I've configured Tomcat to use IBM Java, and again it performed much better then on WebSphere.
With *Tomcat* it takes around **2.5secs** and with *WebSphere* **12secs** to read, process, and write the image (size ~= 200KB).

Is there some IBM JVM specific configuration I can use in order to speed up reading of images?

Here is the extract from the code I use:

```
// srcImagePath & dstImagePath are both pointing 
// to the location outside app servers

BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(srcImagePath));

// here I am only resizing image using com.twelvemonkeys.image.ResampleOp
// from twelvemonkeys library
BufferedImage destImage = resizeImage(image);

ImageIO.write(destImage, "jpg", dstImagePath);
```

Here is the JVM configuration I have used (changed):

**Tomcat 7.0.50**: -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m

**WebSphere 8.5.5**: Initial heap size 512m, Maximum heap size: 1280m

**IBM Java 1.7_64**

**Windows 7**

Is there any WebSphere configuration I am not aware of, that could speed up the processing?

Comment: If you haven't already done so, you could try connecting a profiler to your WebSphere process, and see where time is spent.The difference is quite surprising...

Answer (score 1):

After the profiling, I've found the reason for the slow response.

Most of the time consumed in WebSphere during image processing was caused by
ResampleOp class, specifically:

```
com.twelvemonkeys.image.ResampleOp.resample
```

method was the bottleneck for image resize process. With native Java's [AffineTransform](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html) I was not able to get good quality resized images, therefore I've ended up using [imgscalr](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library/) library. **imgscalr** performs very good in my case (both Tomcat & WebSphere) and with good quality pics.

I am still using Twelvemonkey's JPEGImageReader, for correct reading of CMYK JPEG images.

**UPDATE:**

Resize code I had with ResampleOP was:

```
ResampleOp resampleOp = new ResampleOp(width, height);
BufferedImage rescaledImage = resampleOp.filter(image, null);
```

With the Scalr, code I'm using now is:

```
BufferedImage rescaledImage = Scalr.resize(image, width, height);
```

Comment: But did you figure out why is it slower in WebSphere than Tomcat? Disclaimer: I'm the author of the class question, so I'd like to know why and if possible do something about it. You might want to create an [issue](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/issues) for it as well, if it performs unreasonable. :-)

Comment: First of all, thanx for a great library :) In my updated answer, you can see the code change I've done to solve the performance issue. Unfortunatelly, I could not figure out why the resizing was performing so bad in WebSphere. The problematic method seems to be ResampleOp.filter -> ResampleOp.sinc. If it would be of any help, I will provide my profiling data and sample images.

Comment: Yes, please. :-) Send it over, and I'll have a look.

Comment: PS: The `sinc(x)` method uses `Math.sin(x)`... Could it be that there's a difference in the Math libraries used? Like one is using strict math, and the other not or something like that? Just guessing now, could give better answers with more info...

Comment: Thant was my initial thought as well. But since both Tomcat & WebSphere were running on IBM's JVM, so I really could not understand why there was an performance issue with the ResampleOP. I have created issue on github, please let me know if you need more info from me.

Comment: depending on the platform and the JVM, the default JDK built-in Java2D operations can be hardware accelerated and imgscalr will use them whenever possible - it's entirely possible that ResampleOp was working directly on the RGB values in the BufferedImage which was pulling them out of the hardware accelerated pipeline and directly into the JVM for manipulation.